# Figma design with gradient to Flutter widget

Tags: flutter

I have a simple Figma design which contains two layers

First layer with solid color: `background: #003274;`

Second layer with gradient:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: 0%;
bottom: 0%;

background: radial-gradient(100% 245.99% at 0% 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
border-radius: 0px;
```

Now I'm trying to implement this in Flutter code like this:

```
return new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Color(0xff003274),
      gradient: new RadialGradient(
        colors: [Color.fromARGB(102, 255, 255, 255), Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255)],
        radius: 2.5,
        center: Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    )
);
```

As result I got grey gradient in stead of blue gradient

Could you suggest me how to translate this Figma design whiht gradient to Flutter code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know whether this is the best way, but it works. Just wrap your `Container` within another `Container`, and set its `color` to the bottom layer solid color.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff003274),
      child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          gradient: new RadialGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromARGB(102, 255, 255, 255),
              Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255)
            ],
            radius: 2.5,
            center: Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very mach. It works pretty well :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)